# Is it possible for a site owner's user account to **ever** have a permissions issue?

Tags: users

I continually read posts like this:

> This may sound dumb, but have you set the proper permissions to use it? I spent a good two hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong before realizing I hadn't checked the '[whatever]' box.

As a Han-Solo of D-developers, I never think of permissions, but at desperate moments when Views repeats the same imperious error, doubt creeps in. Could it be permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User #1 only bypasses `user_access()`; if something runs its own access calls, and doesn't call `user_accces()`, that user won't get any special handling.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Any module can set a function for an access callback to simply be "FALSE" and this will apply to uid 1 as well. Everything in core and pretty much every contrib module will be doing things "The Drupal Way" with core permissions and user_access though, which can't restrict uid 1 from doing anything; have a look at the code and you'll see - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/6

Answer (score 1):

Very occasionally yes - my memory is foggy, but I think once instance is if a module doesn't properly use user_access() to check permissions.

I like to toss [Admin role](http://drupal.org/project/adminrole) onto my sites, which makes sure users with that role always have all permissions.

If you are debugging issues, Xdebug can be very helpful. /admin/reports/dblog may also help.

Finally, googling the exact error can shed some more light. Someone else has almost definitely run into it before you.

When all else fails, try the simplest possible solutions you can think of.

Comment: The simplest next step was to recreate a test case. But now I have a test case that's working and still can't get the true content to query properly. (If I knew an emoticon for crying, I'd use it right here)