# Can't use super user account

Tags: 6, users

I have a Drupal 6 installation, and wanted to make some changes for the client. However, this fails, because as soon as I log in with the super user account it says:

> Access Denied: You don't have sufficient permissions to access this page

So I can't even log in using the super user account (uid 1). The password is already reset several times. The cache tables and session tables are emptied. What can I do?

Comment: Do you have a theme set as default but not enabled?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/when-can-uid-1-get-an-access-denied-page?rq=1 Or perhaps a module that is not using user_access correctly?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9740/is-it-possible-for-a-site-owners-user-account-to-ever-have-a-permissions-is?rq=1

Comment: User 1 is supposed to always have all access. The user_access function has `if ($account->uid == 1) { return TRUE; }` so either you have a misbehaving module, or a broken core, or some other unusual error, so we can't really figure what is actually wrong unless you provide more info. (Though obviously guesses can be made, and HSTs doesn't look bad)

Comment: What is the path of the page that you're getting access denied on? Also, have you seen https://drupal.org/node/329274 ?

Answer (score 2):

I hada look into my watchdog table. It said the sessions table was corrupted and needed to be repaired. So I did it, and after that I could login with the super user again. Thanks everybody for helping out, but it was something different this time.

Comment: +1 This is the most common cause of this behavior. Other common possibility can be an improperly configured SSL setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly possible its because of htaccess configuration of your drupal installation which is not ok with server's configuration.

I think it must be because of `+FollowSymLinks`, just edit htaccess in your drupal root and `sites/default/files` directory and comment the line that says:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

and change it to:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
```

and if it still didnt work out try commenting out `Options -Indexes` as well.

by the way it's always good to check your server errors in `cpanel > error logs`

Comment: I am pretty positive that a bad directive, or one that tries to set an option that is disallowed by general server config, will result in a 500 and not a 403.